# Ngin, url:/search => run php /search.php, and url:/my => php my.php

Tags: nginx

Please help me configure Nginx:

1) I have a number of php scripts, and I want to run them with their URL without ".php"
For e.g

- url /search -> run script "/search.php"
- url /bookmark -> run script "/bookmarks.php"
- url / -> run script "/index.php"

2) 404
/asdfasdfasdf - any url, that does not match any specified location and do not lead to static file (image, css) should run /not-found.php with preserving /asdfasdfasdf in URL

Current server section
root /var/www/site/public;
index index.php;

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;         
}

location ~ \.(ico|css|js|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 7d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public,  must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

Comment: By the rules of the board, you are required to demonstrate some attempt of having tried to solve this yourself. So, which rewrite rules did you try, and what errors did they give?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using rewrites

```
location /abcd {
  rewrite ^/abcd\/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\s\+]+)\/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\s\+\(\)\.]+)$ /efgh.php?action=whatever;
}
location /xyz {
  rewrite ^/yxz\/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\s\+]+)$ /rst.php?action=whatever;
}
```

There's probably a more generic way, but if you have a limited number of URLs this may work. This may send you on the right track. I'd probably look at regular expressions, capture groups, and expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some common patterns for implementing extension-less PHP. One such pattern looks like this:

```
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}
location @php {
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```