# Map server to directive of domain in nginx

Tags: nginx

I was wondering if it is possible to map a domain directive to a server.

In our case, we have a api which is served by a Rails instance, then we have a Frontend which is served from a Node server. Ideally i would like Frontend to http://domain.com/* and api to http://domain.com/api*, but is this even possible?

I tried the following (just a snippet).

```
  # Configuration for API.
  server {
    server_name www.domain.com/api;

    location /api {
      try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    ....
  }

  # Configuration for the server
  server {
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    ......
  }
```

However this doesn't seem to work, is it even possible to get the desired? Or do i need one of them to run on a sub domain?

Comment: You may get an idea from my answer to this question http://serverfault.com/questions/772603/ngin-url-search-run-php-search-php-and-url-my-php-my-php/772660#772660

Comment: Thank you @Tim i think that might solve my problem, gonna test it tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is invalid syntax for a `server_name` directive. You have two applications  within the same `server` block. Obviously there is potential for conflicts which you will need to resolve. But to expand on your snippet, you will need to define two named locations, one for each application:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }
    location @proxy {
        ...
    }
    location /api {
        try_files $uri @api;
    }
    location @api {
        ...
    }
}
```